# How to distinguish between the 1st & 3rd person singular conjugation in the subjunctive?

Tags: gramática, verbos, subjuntivo, conjugación

I am learning about the subjunctive and am doing some exercises. I have a quick question on the line below.

> Dudo que venga - I doubt that he'll come

So *venga* is the 1st & 3rd person singular. So if I wanted to say *I doubt that I will come* how would I say that? As I see it, it would be the same? Also, if it was a she not a he, how could I tell the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would say it exactly the same, yes.
Context should make clear if I'm talking about *yo*, *usted*, *él*, *ella* or *ello*:

- In *"Tengo cita con el dentista mañana, dudo que venga a tu casa"* it is clear that *venga* refers to me, since I already said that *I* have a dentist appointment and so *I* might not come.
- In *"Ana está de bajón, dudo que venga mañana a la fiesta"* context is enough to know that *Ana* is the one who might not come to the party tomorrow, because she's feeling down.

If context is not enough, you can make the subject explicit as always, with *dudo que yo venga*, *dudo que ella venga*:

- In *"Ana está cabreada conmigo, dudo que venga"* it is not clear if I doubt that *I* will come (because Ana is upset with me, and she'll be there, and I don't want to see her) or if I doubt that *Ana* will come (because she's upset with me and I'll be coming, so she might not). So you could say *"Ana está cabreada conmigo, dudo que yo venga"* or *"Ana está cabreada conmigo, dudo que ella venga"* to clear it up if necessary.

Comment: Great answer!. Could you change _cabreada_ by _enojada_ so it is more "universal" language? I think the OP is Chinese and a more generic terminology would be more useful for him.